# Find a value of $t$ such that the given vector is parallel to $(2,-3,1)$.

Tags: vector-spaces

> Find a value of $t$ such that the vector $(t^2, -3t, (6-t)^{1/2})$ is parallel to $(2,-3,1)$.

I'm pretty sure a vector is parallel if it's a scalar multiple of the other, so I tried setting each elements of the first vector to the second one and solving for $t$, but they all seem to have different answers, how do I solve this kind of problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, but you're not supposed to set the elements to be equal to one another. That would solve the problem "which $t$ makes this vector *equal* to that vector", which is, as you've discovered, impossible.

What you *should* do is set one vector equal to a scalar multiple of another, which is done like this:
$$
s(2,-3,1)=(t^2, -3t, \sqrt{6-t})
$$
which gives you three equations in two unknowns.

Comment: I'm not sure where I go from here exactly.. I tried setting -3s = -3t.. etc, then pluging s=t into the other equations and solving for t but i get t = 0, -2 for the first two and t = 2,3 ...

Comment: @JL The first should give you $t=0$ or $t=2$.  So $t=2$ works for all three equations.

Comment: So, from the second equation you get $s=t$, which is well and good. The first equation then says $2t=t^2$, which has the two possible solutions $t=0$ and $t=2$. The third equation says $t=\sqrt{6-t}$, but you already know that no solutions other than $0,2$, so you test those, and if any of them work, then good. If none of them work, then there is no working value for $t$.

Comment: oops, for some reason I got t = 0,-2 for the first instead 2. then went crazy for an hour. all is well now that i see my mistake :D now everything seems painfully obvious

Comment: No problem. Just today I was stuck for an hour because I tried to solve a (relatively complicated) quadratic equation by using the formula $\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2+4ac}}{2a}$. Everyone gets stuck on stupid things like that from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. For $(t^2, -3t, (6-t)^{1/2}$ to be parallel to $(2,-3,1)$ it must be $p$ times $(2,-3,1)$, where $p$ is a scalar multiple.
Set up 2 equation by equating any two of the $i$ $j$ and $k$ components and solving them simultaneously for $p$ and $k$. When you have obtained these values, plug back into the original vector to confirm that they are indeed parallel

Comment: can you elaborate more on the part from simultaneously and on?